# pip: Why sometimes installed as egg, sometimes installed as files

Tags: python, pip, egg

Where can you force pip to install as "flat" and not as "egg".

For me it seems random. Sometimes it gets installed as egg, sometime as flat.

`pip help install` shows only an option `--egg` which forces an egg installation. But I could not find a `--flat` option.

The packages are from an own pypiserver, and uploaded like this:

`python setup.py sdist upload -r internal`

Output of pip during install:

```
Best match: foo-client 2015.2
Downloading https://installserver:40443/pypi/packages/foo_client-2015.2.tar.gz
Processing foo_client-2015.2.tar.gz
Writing /home/bar_eins_daad/tmp/easy_install-z20B7b/foo_client-2015.2/setup.cfg
Running foo_client-2015.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /home/bar_eins_daad/tmp/easy_install-z20B7b/foo_client-2015.2/egg-dist-tmp-GO1snX
```

I don't know why `bdist_egg` gets used here. Does it force creating an egg install?

The `setup.py` does use `setuptools` not `distutils`.

The package on our pypiserver looks like this:

```
tar -tzf packages/foo_client-2015.3.tar.gz
```

content:

```
foo_client-2015.2/
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client.egg-info/
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client.egg-info/top_level.txt
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client.egg-info/PKG-INFO
foo_client-2015.2/setup.cfg
foo_client-2015.2/PKG-INFO
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client/
foo_client-2015.2/foo_client/models.py
...
```

**Background**

pip seems to sometimes install packages several times if zipped eggs are installed.

**Update**

I found under which condition the package gets installed as egg: if it gets installed via `python setup.py develop` (it is an install_requires dependency).

If I use `pip install foo_client` it gets installed flat (the way I want it).

**Update2**

The very ugly part: If the egg gets installed, the old version installed flat does not get removed.

Version: pip 1.5.6

Comment: Can you elaborate? The `--egg` option is there to make pip install an egg (binary) distribution if available, rather than to install from source (the default), for example. Can you give us some sample packages that show the difference?

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, our pypiserver is not available for the public. Is there an other way to give you more details?

Comment: Are there no publicly available packages that exhibit this behaviour at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters we mostly install from our own pypiserver. Even packages from pypi.org. We first download to our own pypiserver, then we install from it.

Comment: Then surely you can find a package from among those that illustrate the behaviour you are talking about. This has nothing to do with what server served the package.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't find a package which installs as egg but should not. I updated some infos about our python packages.

Comment: Pip does install the egg *metadata*. That is normal behaviour. The package is still going to end up unzipped in your `site-packages`. Are you saying you have *zipped egg files* there, or are there only `.egg-info` directories there?

Comment: `install_requires` indeed installs the requirement as an egg. It won't remove other versions because what is installed now is only a *installation dependency*. You can remove those again after installation has completed, in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters íf not `install_requires` what should be used in setup.py? I read these docs: https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements.html

Comment: I don't know what problem you are trying to solve there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to have python packages installed flat and not as egg. It should not matter how the package gets installed (via `pip` directly or via `python setup develop`).

Comment: I was talking about the `install_requires` field. Why are you using it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to define a dependency. Example: package foo_client_for_customer_x needs package foo_client. Like documented here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html?highlight=requirements#install-requires. I see no other use case. Why do you ask?

Comment: My mistake, my apologies. I was getting mixed up with *`setup_requires`*. `install_requires` should **not** result in eggs being installed, `pip` will install those correctly still.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not solve the question why I get sometimes zipped eggs, and sometimes not. But it helps.

You can use this in your `~/.distutils.cfg` to avoid installation of zipped eggs:

```
[easy_install]
zip_ok = False
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are the *author* of the package, you can use the flag `zip_safe=False` in `setup.py`.

```
setup(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    ...
    zip_safe = False,
)
```

If you are a *user* who wants to improve the package, you can install it by `pip install -e foo_package`. The option `-e` or `--editable` installs a project in an editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode"), not zipped. It creates a link from source into `site-packages` and compiles `.../bin` scripts, but it doesn't copy the source into "site-packages". Those packages can not be updated automatically. It is the main reason why it is not intended as a usual way of installing packages, but only for those that need to be customized or fixed.

Edit: [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a typical framework that requires `zip_safe=False` for its applications, because they are not a pure Python, but they contain also templates with html, css, i18n resources etc. Is your question related to Django?

Comment: Sad, I am not the author of the package. I found a solution now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964960/pip-why-sometimes-installed-as-egg-sometimes-installed-as-files/29127158#29127158

Comment: This is actually pretty useful to control the creations of *.egg folders when you write your own package. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, I just fixed a django package :-D

Answer (score 2):

I was having this **egg-only** install problem, and it turned out I had failed to git add the `__init__.py` in the root of my package. It was driving me crazy that this would work:

```
pip install .
```

...but this would fail:

```
mkdir /tmp/piptest
cd /tmp/piptest
git clone $OLDPWD .
pip install .
```

It was hard to notice the difference using `diff -r . $OLDPWD` because there are so many non-committed pyc files and development tool scripts.

This is probably not the answer for this OP, but I hope it helps someone who Googles "pip only installing the egg" as I did.

Comment: Adding a subfolder for my package (and an `__init__.py` inside, necessary?) was the answer for me. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, @BrianPeterson. But honestly, I put answers like this on the questions that Google leads me to because at some point years from now, I'll need it again.

Answer (score 0):

[Some docs](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag) say:

> For maximum performance, Python packages are best installed as zip files.

and

> You can pass a True or False value for the zip_safe argument to the
>   setup() function, or you can omit it. If you omit it, the bdist_egg
>   command will analyze your project’s contents to see if it can detect
>   any conditions that would prevent it from working in a zipfile.

So it's probably fine unless... it's not fine in your case. My project tried to read files and failed due to the zipping.

Notably, this only happened with `python setup.py install`, not `pip install .` @guettli's fix worked fine, but I put it in `setup.cfg`:

```
[easy_install]
zip_ok = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as @guettli and solved it by unzipping and extracting the archive first then running:

pip -e install /srv/mypkg-1.1.0

where /srv/mypkg-1.1.0/ is the top level directory of project/package that has a setup.py file in it.

mypkg-1.1.0 was installed in site-packages and mypkg.py was listed in [virtualenv]/bin

note: '-e' flag is optional.

Thanks

Comment: Since posting I've learned 'pip install' with '-e', editable option; installs the package in 'devloper mode'. A /srv/mypkg-1.1.0/mypkg.egg-info directory is created in the project directory.  The source code can be  edited without building the package each time. **Not recommended for a production install**.  Therefore as per my original post, I'm unsure whether installing from tarball or from flat file makes the difference as the first time I installed it my tarball was in /tmp and for all I know the egg-info directory may have created there. I'll have to test to confirm.