# Cx_Freeze cannot find pkg_resources/*.*'

Tags: python, setuptools, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build an EXE using a cx_Freeze setup.py file with the following command:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

The command's output ends with:

> Copying data from package pkg_resources... error: [Error 3] The system
>   cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources/*.*'

I'm not sure what to make of it. I've checked and the setuptools' egg exists, and inside it there is a pgk_resources library, and I'm not sure what to do.

I'm using a conda installation and python2.7.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Yiftach does the problem still occur?     I am facing the same problem.                                                                                                  error: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\
\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg\\pkg_resources/*.*' 
                                                                                                   
However, in my case the there is no folder inside site-packeges\\setuptools-27*

Answer (score 2):

That's because `cx_Freeze` cannot work with subpackages of packages installed as packed `.egg`s. A normal Python installation uses `pip` which always unpacks `.egg`s, unlike Anaconda.

The corresponding issue: [Failed to find module in subpackage in zipped egg · Issue #120 · anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/120). It links to the [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-requests/90/finder-can-now-deal-mixed-slashes-paths/diff) with the fix:

```diff
diff --git a/cx_Freeze/finder.py b/cx_Freeze/finder.py
--- a/cx_Freeze/finder.py
+++ b/cx_Freeze/finder.py
@@ -61,6 +61,15 @@
         If the module is found, this returns information in the same format
         as :func:`imp.find_module`. Otherwise, it returns None.
         """
+        # FIX: retrieve_loadable_module dict uses paths with OS's separator
+        # as keys. However the path received as argument can have mixed
+        # slashes. This may cause some searches to fail when they should
+        # work. One case where this seems critical is when there are
+        # subpackages inside an egg package.
+        #
+        # See `record_loadable_module` method to see how mixed slashes
+        # happen.
+        path = os.path.normpath(path)
         try:
             return self.retrieve_loadable_module(path, modulename)
         except KeyError:
```

Replacing all the `.egg`s you have with unpacked versions with `pip install --upgrade` as suggested in the other answer is only a temporary solution - until you get another `.egg`.

Comment: You wrote "A normal Python installation uses pip which always unpacks .egg" I use Python 3.6 which does not unzip the egg. It installed setuptools as zipped egg. After renaming the egg to ".zip" and moving both directories (setuptools and pkg_resources) into the site-packages directory, it works.

Comment: @guettli see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964960/pip-why-sometimes-installed-as-egg-sometimes-installed-as-files

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

which I learned from Ali Akdurak's answer here [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources?rq=1)