# Import error using KivyMD and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, kivy, material-design, pyinstaller, kivymd

When i try to use pyinstaller with '*KivyMD Kitchen Sink*' (--one file --debug --clean) i get this:

```
File "kivymd\theming.py", line 17, in <module>
File "site-packages\kivy\core\text\__init__.py", line 248, in register
# and pass it in context.config token
OSError: File C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI92522\kivymd\fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttfs not found
Failed to execute script main
```

I try to use:

```
if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

in main.py but nothing changed.

Also, i copied Roboto-Regular.ttf to the main.exe's directory without success.

Pyinstaller is working well with other Kivy apps.

**UPDATE:**

I found a temporaly solution. I used pyinstaller's `--onedir` command with main.py instead main.spec file:

```
wine pyinstaller --onedir main.py
```

Then, i copied kivymd folder (../site-packages/kivyMD) to my app's folder, and the app started without errors.

Anyways, I would like freeze app as a `--onefile`, Any suggesions? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cx\_Freeze cannot find pkg\_resources/\*.\*'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609043/cx-freeze-cannot-find-pkg-resources)

Comment: Probably the same effect of mixed slashes as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609043/cx-freeze-cannot-find-pkg-resources

Comment: Could you reduce your app to a [mcve]? It's either the file not being included, or the execution logic not finding it, possibly due to mixed slashes.

Comment: The error code says "Roboto-Regular.ttfs not found" but font's extension should be .ttf

Answer (score 2):

Since **[KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) 0.102.1** there is PyInstaller hook. You can just specify KivyMD's hook directory in your .spec file:

```py
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path

a = Analysis(
    # ...
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    # ...
)
```

You can see [Kitchen Sink's pyinstaller.spec file](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/pyinstaller.spec) and [example in KivyMD's documentation](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/tools/packaging/pyinstaller/__init__.py) on how to use this hook.

---

The full pyinstaller.spec file will be:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
path = os.path.abspath(".")
a = Analysis(
    ["main.py"],
    pathex=[path],
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=None,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=None)
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    name="app_name",
    console=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no hook for kivymd in pyinstaller, it would not recognize package and therefore will be import errors. So what you can do is write a small hook for pyinstaller so it can be recognized during packing.

Perhaps try using my snippet. Tested on Windows 10

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import (
    collect_data_files, 
    copy_metadata,
    collect_submodules
)

datas = copy_metadata('kivymd')
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('kivymd')

datas = collect_data_files('kivymd')
```

Reference to PyInstaller hook
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/eiNjel/RgdLkG

Create this file in pyinstaller/hooks and you should be fine.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

- use `pip install auto-py-to-exe`
- run `auto-py-to-exe` (in cmd)
- select additional option in `auto-py-exe` ui
- in additional file, add kivymd folder which is copied from site package (`auto -py-exe(ui)`)